# Leaflet GeoJSON style and labeling

Tags: leaflet, geojson, labeling, style

I'm trying to add a GeoJSON polygon layer from a file, give it a specific style and show the label (ToolTip) but couldn't find a way to do it in a single function call
.
I only found different code samples doing each task alone (styling data or showing labels), then I mixed both codes and got something weird, it just created another layer on top of the previous one.

```
  var geojson = L.geoJSON(myGeoJson);

  L.geoJson(myGeoJson,{
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.CASOS.toString(), {permanent: true}).openTooltip();
    }
    }).addTo(map)

  L.geoJSON(myGeoJson, {
    style: myStyle
    }).addTo(map);
```

How could I show labels and style the polygons without creating a stack of layers?

EDIT: I edited the question because I think I was unclear, I want to style the data, not the labels.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/CrqkR/6/

Comment: that code doesn't style any data

Comment: most likely you need polygon to points then label style via css here is a wingdings style label http://jsfiddle.net/0z9fak6o/

Comment: Do you want to have one custom style for all tooltips or you want to style each individual tooltip differently?

Comment: First I'd like to have one custom style for all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: '#E31A1C',
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}

L.geoJson(myGeoJson, {
            style: style,
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.CASOS.toString(), { permanent: true });
        }}).addTo(map);
```

The line

```
style:style
```

does the styling, and the next 2 lines does the labeling. I just had to separate them by a comma inside a single command instead of creating another command.  Now it created a single layers instead of a stack of two layers.

Answer (score 5):

To give all tooltips your own style, you just modify Leaflet built in CSS class `leaflet-tooltip`.

For example, if you create the following CSS class:

```
.leaflet-tooltip {
  border-color: #3399FF;
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

then the default tooltip

[image]

would become

[image]

If you want to give some tooltip individual style, then you can use `className` option, which `L.tooltip` inherits from `DivOverlay` class.

Your tooltip binding could then look something like:

```
layer.bindTooltip(
  feature.properties.CASOS.toString(),
  {permanent: true, className: 'myClass', direction: 'center'}
).openTooltip();
```

Comment: I'd like to style the GeoJSON data itself, not it's tooltip (label).
But thanks for the information, that's really useful for other purposes.
Maybe I was unclear in the question, so I will edit it.

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/example.html. It seems to have answer to your question.

Comment: I looked through tutorial and examples but only could find the codes for each task, and when I try to use both codes in a single code it don't work.